# Strange form of Taylor's Theorem for linearization

Tags: taylor-expansion

I came across a form of Taylor's Theorem that I have never seen before. The author states it without proof and says that it can be found in any calculus book, but I can't find it. Could somebody please show me the proof or point me towards a reference with the proof?

The author says:

If $f : R^n \rightarrow R$ is continuously differentiable and $p \in R^n$, then

$f(x+p) = f(x) + \nabla f(x+tp) p$

for some $t\in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the mean value Theorem:
Define $$g: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: t \mapsto f(x+tp)$$
and notice that
$$ g(1)-g(0)=f(x+p)-f(x).$$
By applying the mean value Theorem to $g$ we know there exists a $\xi \in [0,1]$ such that $g(1)-g(0)= g'(\xi).(1-0)$. Now use that
$$g'(\xi) = \nabla f(x+\xi p) \cdot p. $$